# In Linux kernel, header inclusion error

Tags: linux, macros, header, kernel

When I included "asm/xen/hypercall.h" in my source code in kernel,

I got a this error message. How can I solve it?

```
 include/linux/stddef.h:8:16: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
 #define NULL ((void *)0)
                ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:221:28: note: in expansion of macro 'NULL'
 #define __parainstructions NULL
                            ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:703:35: note: in expansion of macro '__parainstructions'
 extern struct paravirt_patch_site __parainstructions[],
                                   ^
include/linux/stddef.h:8:23: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
 #define NULL ((void *)0)
                       ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:221:28: note: in expansion of macro 'NULL'
 #define __parainstructions NULL
                            ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:703:35: note: in expansion of macro '__parainstructions'
 extern struct paravirt_patch_site __parainstructions[],
                                   ^
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target 'drivers/oxen/fallback.o' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

XEN functionality depends on PARAVIRT (see arch/x86/xen/Kconfig).

But line

```
#define __parainstructions NULL
```

at `arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:221` is executed only when PARAVIRT is *disabled*.  So, your shouldn't use XEN headers in that case.

Comment: Thank you for reply but is there no way to do? Could you give me a advice?

Comment: Check if you have `CONFIG_PARAVIRT` set in include/generated/autoconf.h

Comment: @myaut I checked it but that set does not exist in autoconf.h

Comment: The only way for use XEN functionality is recompiling kernel with XEN configuration option enabled. For doing that, you should also enable PARAVIRT option(and, probably, some other ones). You can use `make menuconfig` for configure kernel, in that case `/` key can be used for search particular options.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your help. I resolve that problem and I can include hypercall.h now. But there are one more error. In HYPERVISOR_hvm_op func, there are hypercall_page symbol, but compiler prints "Undefined". Do you know what is this problem?

Comment: @nicelhc13: `hypercall_page` is exported using EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL, so you need `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` in you module for use it.

Comment: Hmm, then I have no idea, why it is so. Does `hypercall_page` symbol exist in kernel's Module.symvers file(just `grep` it)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No.. there is not in the symver file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I found http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2008-07/msg00343.html . That URL explain about hypercall_page, but I don't understand. Please could you understand what mean is? and if I want to use hypercall_page, what is the method? Best regards

Comment: @nicelhc13: This thread notes, that `hypercall_page` is defined in special way(in assemply). But that fact shouldn't affect on its usage. Another guess: is Xen actually built (`arch/x86/xen/` contains .o files)?